# Storing numbers entered via an input/form into an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, for-loop, input, jsx

Fairly new to React and still getting familiar. Looking to store entries via input/form into an array, which I'll later be iterating over to match this.state.value too

see 'summary' for more details on edited code (as of 3/1)

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

class TMKform extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { tmks: []};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    //Definig form here which value is the input value, later to be concatted to tmk[]
    var form = this._input.value;
    var tmk = this.state.value;
    var allTmks = this.state.tmks.concat([form]);
    //Clears input on 'submit'
    this.setState({value: ''});
    this.setState({tmks: allTmks});
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
  console.log(this.state.tmks);

    return (
      <div className = "tmkSearch">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Enter TMK Here: <br />
            <input type="text" name="TMK Number" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} ref={(el) => this._input = el}/>
          </label> <br />
          <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<TMKform />, document.getElementById('app'));

module.exports = TMKform;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to clear the state once the submit has been handled.

Comment: thanks @Joe do you mind providing an example on how to clear the state?

Comment: `this.setState({value: ''});`

Comment: put that at the bottom of `handleSubmit()`

Comment: I switched out my bottom <input> to the following <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>, which is clearing input on submit click

Comment: yep, yep. handleSubmit now looks like this `handleSubmit(event) {
    var tmk = this.state.value;
    var tmkArray = [];

    tmkArray.push(tmk);

    console.log(tmkArray);
    this.setState({ value: ''});
    event.preventDefault();
  }`

Comment: where do I add an array to store each submission?

Comment: I would create the array in the constructor, like the one you have commented out in your question. Then just push into it in `handleSubmit()`.

Comment: thanks @Joe I uncommented array and added a push in handleSubmit() and it isn't reaching array. I can't really see the error but I believe it says 'uncaught array, etc. etc.'